# Creating index for Amazon S3 bucket keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What is the general strategy to index S3 keys as such it would be possible to query keys? Knowing multiple S3 operations cannot be in a transaction, then it's not possible to create an index in such a manner:

```
putObject(...);
indexObject(...)
```

Since the method `putIndex` here is not guaranteed to be in the same transaction of the previous method, so wire or other connection error would mean the first operation would not have an index.

Comment: What do you mean by "index S3 keys"? What is `putIndex`? Please edit your question to add more details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein index keys to be searchable by query

Answer (score 2):

There is no capability for "searching" Amazon S3 keys. The closest capability is to specify a `Prefix`, which can be a directory path, or partial name of an object.

A `ListObjects` call only returns 1000 objects at a time. This means that large buckets with 100,000+ objects can be slow to retrieve.

If you need a fast, searchable index you can **store a list of keys in DynamoDB**. Then, use Amazon S3 Events to trigger AWS Lambda functions when objects are added and deleted, to update DynamoDB.

Alternatively, if you have a large number of objects but they do not change frequently, you can use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to obtain a daily or weekly CSV file with a list of all objects.

Comment: I am thinking of implementing a similar approach as to what Google App Engine did for its datastore considering its underlying system is based on storage with similar limitations with S3.  And it seems the way they have achieved it is by structuring the keys properly to allow range scans