# Reading from s3 bucket with millions of s3 objects in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket with millions of objects and each object is named with a UNIX timestamp as shown in the image. What I am trying to do is to read all the s3 bucket objects between two timestamps and this is the code I am using to do that.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket')
START_TM = 1655484320
END_TM = 1655484380
dfs = []
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix):
    if float(obj.key[-12:]) > float(START_TM) and float(obj.key[-12:]) <= 
    float(END_TM):
       response = obj.get()
       kv = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
       kv = json.loads(kv)
       kv = flatten_dict(kv)
       df = pd.DataFrame([kv])
       dfs.append(df)
```

The above code works but the problem is it first reads all the s3 objects(Bucket objects increases by 100000 everyday) and then filters the objects based on the filter condition which is impacting the downstream processes and as the objects increase it really slows down. What would be the best way to index s3 objects so I can read the objects with a filter in python with minimal latency(< 10 seconds)?

[image: s3 bucket image example]

Comment: Use [S3 invenotry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html)

Comment: Does s3 inventory work for JSON objects as each s3 object is a JSON file?

Comment: It least all objects in your bucket. Once you get that list, you can then process only the objects that you want from your python code.

Comment: In addition to the S3 inventory suggestion, you _really_ should be storing these objects prefixed by date with something like "yyyy/mm/dd/timestamp" so you can use S3 prefix searches to quickly find new files.

Comment: It appears that you are receiving an 82-byte file every minute. I would recommend that you combine those objects together into fewer, larger objects. You can do this by using Amazon Athena (and the [$path variable](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/find-s3-source-file-athena-table-row/)). Having fewer objects would not only avoid the need to scan millions of object names, it would also avoid the overhead of opening all the individual objects.

Comment: Hey @JohnRotenstein I came across this solution of yours https://stackoverflow.com/a/62443665/10713420. I think this would be more suitable for my problem but can you give me more details on this? Like how can I retrieve objects using lambda?

Comment: Keeping your own database of objects would merely speed the selection of _which_ files you wish to read. It won't speed the actual activity of reading through all the files. Given that your data is only 82 bytes per file, you'd be better simply putting the data in the database, rather than using a database as an index to the files. One million files x 82 bytes = 82MB, which is a rather small amount of data these days. I'd suggest you combine them into larger files and simply read through ALL the data rather than selectively reading files.

Comment: One of the down processes includes computing data for every 5-minute, 1 hr, and 5 hr time window so I need to extract the data belongs to the respective time interval so I thought that solution would be ideal in my case rather than reading all the objects in s3.

Comment: And I get 1 million records every day as we are unloading patient monitor data into s3 .